# Pandas sum corresponding values based on values in another column

Tags: pandas

df1 contains Itemlist1 and Itemlist2 where each cell can contain any number of items. df2 contains Price and Cost of each item.

Want to obtain a final df with 2 new columns, Totalprice and Totalcost, added to df1. The Totalprice and Totalcost is the sum of all the items in each row of df1.

Managed to arrive at df3 where each item is put in a separate cell. Any suggestion from here please. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your df3, do the `replace`, then `sum` with `axis=1`

```
cost_dict = dict(zip(df2.Itemcode,df2.Cost))
price_dict = dict(zip(df2.Itemcode,df2.Price))
df1['totalcost'] = df3.replace(cost_dict).sum(axis=1)
df1['totalprice'] = df3.replace(price_dict).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you @BENY, your solution works well.